# how to find a text in some files with same name

Tags: grep, find

I have some files named savedsearches.conf in several directories, I need to know in which savedsearches.conf is present a string (i.e. "search1".
I tried with command

```
find /opt/splunk/ -name "savedsearches.conf" -exec grep -i "search1" {} \;
```

But in this way I only see the texts that contains "search1" but I don't know the path of the file that contains the text.

I would like something like path, file name and string. Is it possible?

Comment: Such questions belong to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use `-H` option wit `GNU grep`:

```
find /opt/splunk/ -name "savedsearches.conf" -exec grep -iH "search1" {} \;
```

Example output:

```
/opt/splunk/savedsearches.conf:search1
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as accepted so that other people know your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case to use btool

`/opt/splunk/bin/splunk btool savedsearches.conf list — debug | grep search1`